# Drupal session won't destroy after relocate domain

Tags: php, apache, session, subdomain

We had an outdated typo3 based site and wanted a new one based on Drupal7 
so we created it in the same server.

**mydomain.org** was on ***home/mydomain.org/public/*** so we created the new one 
in ***/home/newmysite/mydomain.org/public/*** with **new.mydomain.org** as subdomain address.

Once we were ready to run the new drupal site, we asked our host to change *new.mydomain.org* to *mydomain.org.*
When the change was done, drupal shows:

> Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session
>   module's ini settings at this time in drupal_environment_initialize()
>   (line 707 of
>   /home/newmysite/mydomain.org/public/includes/bootstrap.inc).

I'm unable to start session as administrator in drupal or run different scripts like [tinyshell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tiny-shell/?source=recommended) or [phpshell](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/) because they need to create a session

I change drupal's settings.php:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 0); 
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
```

(currently back to defaults cause didn't work)

I also did a script with session_destroy(); nothing happened.

info:

```
htaccess: php_flag session.auto_start   off

phpinfo(): session.auto_start = off
```